# unit testing in web api with N tier without actual database calls

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, mstest, web-api-testing, vs-unit-testing-framework

I am writing Unit Tests for My Web API application ,created with .net Core. I use MSTest with MOQ for mocking.

It has many layers as below.

**Controller => Manager classes => Facade classes => Contract class**

I am providing entity in controller that I have mocked.

```
[TestMethod]
public void InvoiceUpdateFinanceTest_Success()
{
    var mock = mockFactory.OutstandingInvoicesDetailsMock();

    dataController.InvoiceUpdateFinance(mock);
    Assert.IsTrue(true);
}
```

**Contract Class** is creating DB connection instance and does database calls

Code sample in Contract Layer is as below

```
public class GradeWiseSlab : IMaintainContract
{
  

    IDbConnection _db = new DBModel().InstanceCreation();
    
    DynamicParameters dp = new DynamicParameters();
    public MaintainContractEntities MaintainContractEntities { get; set; }
    public void SaveData()
    {
        dp.Add("@N_VENDOR_ID", MaintainContractEntities.VendorId);
        dp.Add("@N_CONTRACT_SUB_TYPE_ID", MaintainContractEntities.SubContractType);
        dp.Add("@N_PAYMENT_TERM", MaintainContractEntities.PaymentTerm);
        dp.Add("@S_TRANSACTION_CURRENCY", MaintainContractEntities.TransactionCurrency);
        dp.Add("@S_DOC_NAME", MaintainContractEntities.DocNames);
        dp.Add("@S_APPROVAL_STATUS", MaintainContractEntities.ApproalStatus);
        dp.Add("@D_FROM_DATE", MaintainContractEntities.FromDate);
        dp.Add("@D_TO_DATE", MaintainContractEntities.ToDate);
        this._db.Query(Constant.SP_GRADE_WISE_SLAB, dp, commandTimeout: 0, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
}
```

How can I write test cases which shall cover all the layers i.e from controller to contract but no actual DB to touch?

I am not using Entity Framework, **I am using Dapper library**.

Answer (score 0):

if you were using EntityFramework, EF now has a InMemoryDatabase.

But that does not seem to be the case.

I have to rewrite some of your "terms" since you are not showing alot of code and the terms are a little confusing.

Controller (WebApiLayer)=> Manager classes (BusinessLogic Layer) => DataLayer (this is where the calls to stored procedures actually exist).  From your description, I would say my "DataLayer" is your "Contract" layer......imho, "Contract" is an confusing and ambiguous name....and not a great name for a datalayer.  But I digress.

With the above design, you would INJECT some IDataLayer object (for example, IEmployeeDataLayer) interface into your Manager (EmployeeManager : IEmployeeManager).  You would have a "real" concrete EmployeeTheRealOneDataLayer object ... and you would also be able to mock IEmployeeDomainDataLayer .. in order to unit test your EmployeeManager object.

I actually have a "close" sample here:

https://github.com/granadacoder/dotnet-core-on-linux-one/blob/master/src/Bal/Managers/EmployeeManager.cs

```
public class EmployeeManager : IEmployeeManager
{
    private readonly ILogger<EmployeeManager> logger;
    private readonly IEmployeeDataLayer iedl;

    public EmployeeManager(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IEmployeeDataLayer iedl)
    {
        this.logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<EmployeeManager>();
        this.iedl = iedl;
    }
```

With my unit test code, I would Mock IEmployeeDataLayer , to be able to test the EmployeeManager class.

You question is..how do I test the "real" EmployeeDataLayer without hitting a real database.

This is the i-dont-think-it-exists breaking point.  All of that code in the datalayer is coded to (really really) hit a database.

So this is where **holy wars** start.  Some will say "wire it to a sqlexpress database"......but that IMHO, is when these stop becoming unit tests (not running only in memory)..but become more ***functional*** tests.

Since you are not using EF, you probably have to make a decision.  Be "ok" with writing unit-tests against your business logic layer...and "skip" the DataLayer. In fact, I will put the below attribute on my data-layer classes.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.excludefromcodecoverageattribute?view=netcore-3.1

Your other choice is to move to something that is more like this : (EF in memory)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Personally, (and I actually do this when not using EF) (and I also use Dapper because Dapper performs well).......I skip UNIT testing the datalayer.  (Emphasis on the "unit" testing)

But our QA will write FUNCTIONAL tests against a real database engine (think SqlSExpress).  The caveat here is that they have to be able to (we pick once a week) completely DELETE/FLUSH the "qa database"....and rebuild it from seed data.  This prevents people writing functional tests...looking for hard coded surrogate-(primary-keys) on the tables....but forces looking for items by unique-constraints instead.  Aka, it prevents getting "too married" to a specific data inside the qa functional testing database).
(Note, this is a similar concept with the EF In Memory Database...because when you start unit tests with an EF In Memory db, it essentially "is empty" at startup).

PS

You can see a more EF oriented project setup here:
https://github.com/granadacoder/oracle-ef-issues-demo/tree/master/src

PPS

I'm not saying the ideas above are an exhaustive list of possibilities.  But when other ideas start crossing the line of "just being in memory"....that's when these mini holy wars start.  I am very firm in our company about the "in memory" line in the sand.  We used to have alot of "MyProject.Tests.csproj", and this could refer to unit-tests or functional-tests.  Now I "strongly encourage" the projects be called "MyProject.UnitTests.csproj" OR "MyProject.FunctionalTests.csproj" to disambiguate.  Not everybody loves my "draw line in the sand" approach.